# ImageButton image not shown/updated at runtime after fragment transition

Tags: java, android

I am working on some [Android app](https://developer.android.com/about) with single [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), named `MainActivity` and several [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment). Now, through application usage at some point the application fetches images from target device local storage and shows them for selection in `PhotoPickerFragment`, like shown in following screenshot:
[image: Image selection fragment]
`PhotoPickerFragment` also has its `PhotoPickerAdapter` for showing contents in [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView). To transfer selected image between `Fragments` I have written following chunk of code inside [`PhotoPickerAdapter`'s ArrayAdapter getView() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter?hl=en#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) :

```
public View getView(int position,
    @Nullable View convertView,
    @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    PhotoPickerRecord photoPickerRecord=getItem(position);

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_photo_picker_delegate,
            parent,
            false);
    }

    ImageView ivPhotoPickerDelegate=convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPhotoPickerDelegate);

    ivPhotoPickerDelegate.setImageBitmap(photoPickerRecord.scaledPhoto);
    ivPhotoPickerDelegate.setOnClickListener(v->
    {
        MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)getContext();
        NewPlantFragment newPlantFragment=(NewPlantFragment)mainActivity.getNewPlantFragment();
        Bundle selectedRecordBundle=new Bundle();
        ByteArrayOutputStream selectedPhotoStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String encodedSelectedPhoto=new String();

        selectedRecordBundle.putString(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_URI_KEY,
            photoPickerRecord.uri.toString());

        photoPickerRecord.scaledPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
            100,
            selectedPhotoStream);
        encodedSelectedPhoto=Base64.encodeToString(selectedPhotoStream.toByteArray(),
            Base64.DEFAULT);

        selectedRecordBundle.putString(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_KEY,
            encodedSelectedPhoto);
        newPlantFragment.setArguments(selectedRecordBundle);
        mainActivity.switchToScreen(newPlantFragment);
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Selected image is, as you can see, packed into [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) and then `Fragment` switch (from `PhotoPickerFragment` to `NewPlantFragment`) occurs. Target `NewPlantFragment` has declared target [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton) in it (red background is for test purposes only, will be removed):

as you can also see from screenshot:
[image: Android Studio ImageButton declaration screenshot]
Now, after fragment switcing, [NewPlantFragment.OnResume() is called](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment):

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    this.updatePlantPhoto(this.getArguments());
}
```

and them we apply transfered image to `ibPhoto` `ImageButton` in `updatePlantPhoto` method:

```
private void updatePlantPhoto(Bundle plantPhotoInfoBundle)
{
    if((plantPhotoInfoBundle!=null)&&
       (plantPhotoInfoBundle.size()>0))
    {
        if(plantPhotoInfoBundle.containsKey(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_URI_KEY)&&
                (plantPhotoInfoBundle.containsKey(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_KEY)))
        {
            byte[] selectedPlantPhotoByteArray=Base64.decode(plantPhotoInfoBundle.getString(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_KEY),
                    Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap reconstructedSelectedPlantPhoto=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(selectedPlantPhotoByteArray,
                    0,
                    selectedPlantPhotoByteArray.length);

            this.imgBtnPhoto.setImageBitmap(reconstructedSelectedPlantPhoto);

            plantPhotoInfoBundle.clear();
            this.setArguments(plantPhotoInfoBundle);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `ibPhoto` `ImageButton` is not updated, there is still red rectangle with no image visible as you can se from screenshot:
[image: Image not updated screenshot]
Now, I've been trying to debug this problem and in debug process, I can see the selected image is decoded correctly with help of `Android Studio`, I can see decoded Image inside debugger. Why the `ImageButton`'s image is not updated?

**UPDATE 1**

On request on @JornRigter, I am sending screenshot of debug situation with breakpoint:
[image: Debug situation]
As you can see, selected image is decoded.

**UPDATE 2**

I have moved all image processing and images loading to [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)'s and therefore introduced `PhotoDecoder` and `PhotoEncoder`:

```
package com.mikroelektronika.guestnotificationsystem.PhotoPicker;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Base64;

public class PhotoDecoder extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private static final String TAG=PhotoDecoder.class.getSimpleName();

    public PhotoDecoder()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... selectedImages)
    {
        byte[] selectedImageByteArray=Base64.decode(selectedImages[0],
            Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap reconstructedImage=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(selectedImageByteArray,
            0,
            selectedImageByteArray.length);

        return reconstructedImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap reconstructedImage)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(reconstructedImage);
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.mikroelektronika.guestnotificationsystem.PhotoPicker;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class PhotoEncoder extends AsyncTask<PhotoPickerRecord, Void, String>
{
    private static final String TAG=PhotoEncoder.class.getSimpleName();

    public PhotoEncoder()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(PhotoPickerRecord... photoPickerRecords)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream selectedPhotoStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        photoPickerRecords[0].scaledPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
            100,
            selectedPhotoStream);

        return Base64.encodeToString(selectedPhotoStream.toByteArray(),
            Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String finalImage)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(finalImage);
    }
}
```

and I've triple checked with debugger, they both work fine. I've also moved images loading into `PhotoPickerAdapter` into `AsyncTask`, so GUI is not blocked anymore and I can show `ProgressFragment`, but this is not the topic right now:

```
public void populateAdapter()
{
    PhotosLoadingFragment photosLoadingFragment=PhotosLoadingFragment.newInstance();

    class PhotoLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<PhotoPickerRecord>>
    {
        private final String TAG=PhotoLoader.class.getSimpleName();

        private final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME=Environment.
            getExternalStorageDirectory().
            getPath()+
            "/DCIM/Camera";
        private final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID=
            getBucketId(CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME);

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<PhotoPickerRecord> doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            ArrayList<PhotoPickerRecord> imagesDataSource=new ArrayList<>();
            final String[] projection=
                {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                };
            final String selection=MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID+"=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs=
                {
                    CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID
                };
            final Cursor cursor=getContext().
                getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                final int dataColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                do
                {
                    final String data=cursor.getString(dataColumn);
                    PhotoPickerRecord photoPickerRecord=new PhotoPickerRecord();

                    photoPickerRecord.uri=Uri.parse(data);
                    photoPickerRecord.scaledPhoto=ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPickerRecord.uri.getPath()),
                        256,
                        256);

                    imagesDataSource.add(photoPickerRecord);
                } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();

            return imagesDataSource;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            photosLoadingFragment.show(parentFragmentManager,
                null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PhotoPickerRecord> imagesDataSource)
        {
            clear();
            addAll(imagesDataSource);
            photosLoadingFragment.dismiss();
        }

        @NonNull
        private String getBucketId(@NonNull final String path)
        {
            return String.valueOf(path.toLowerCase().hashCode());
        }
    }

    new PhotoLoader().execute();
}
```

Now, after `Fragment` transition in target's fragment [onResume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onResume()), the target [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton)'s image is changed with method `updatePlantPhoto()`:

```
private void updatePlantPhoto(Bundle plantPhotoInfoBundle) throws Exception
{
    if((plantPhotoInfoBundle!=null)&&
       (plantPhotoInfoBundle.size()>0))
    {
        if(plantPhotoInfoBundle.containsKey(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_KEY))
        {
            this.imgBtnPhoto.setImageBitmap(new PhotoDecoder().
                execute(plantPhotoInfoBundle.getString(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_KEY)).
                get());

            plantPhotoInfoBundle.clear();
            this.setArguments(plantPhotoInfoBundle);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also triple checked `Fragment`'s arguments and the image indeed is contained in [Fragment's Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle). Here is also target's `Fragment` `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    try
    {
        this.updatePlantPhoto(this.getArguments());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and `ImageButton`'s is still not changed. WHY?!?!?!?!

**UPDATE 3**

According to @Darkman hint, I've checked the selected image - it is ok. After all background tasks, the selected image arrives into target `Fragment` via [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) and is seen and ok in debugger, as you can see from screenshot:
[image: Debugger breakpoint of checking the selected image]

**UPDATE 4**
I have also checked selecting following image types:

- [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)
- [JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)
- [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF)
- [HEIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format#HEIC:_HEVC_in_HEIF)

None of them works, selected image still not shown.

**UPDATE 5**
According to @Darkman hint, here are conclusions:

- `updatePlantPhoto()` gets called 2 times
- `onResume()` gets called 2 times also

which is ok. I've uploaded some small `32x32` and `64x64` icons to phone and when I select each of them, the selected image is still not shown. How to check refresh?
**UPDATE 6**
Once again according to user @Darkman's hint, I've tried:

- [SetBackground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
- [SetForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setForeground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

with following code:

```
private void updatePlantPhoto(Bundle plantPhotoInfoBundle) throws Exception
{
    Bitmap selectedPhoto=null;
    BitmapDrawable selectedPhotoDrawable=null;

    if((plantPhotoInfoBundle!=null)&&
       (plantPhotoInfoBundle.size()>0))
    {
        if(plantPhotoInfoBundle.containsKey(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_KEY))
        {
            try
            {
                selectedPhoto=new PhotoDecoder().execute(plantPhotoInfoBundle.getString(BundleKeys.SELECTED_PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_KEY))
                    .get();
                selectedPhotoDrawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                    selectedPhoto);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.ibPhotoSelector.setForeground(selectedPhotoDrawable);

            plantPhotoInfoBundle.clear();
            this.setArguments(plantPhotoInfoBundle);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, in the debugger everyhing is ok. Nothing works!

Comment: I think your bug might have to do with the ``compress`` method you use. From the docs: ``This method may take several seconds to complete, so it should only be called from a worker thread.`` "I can see decoded Image inside debugger" -> What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: @JornRigter I've updated my question with screenshot of debug situation.

Comment: Why not do an extra check on the compressed bitmap to check either it's null or not. Seems like the culprit is somewhere there. What happen if you set a small bitmap without the need to compress?

Comment: @Darkman I've updated my question, have checked the image, it is ok! Honestly, I do not know what to do anymore ...

Comment: My last suggestions would be 1) Check how many times `updatePlantPhoto()` is called? 2) `onResume()` might be called multiple times. 3) If with a small image let say 32x32 without compression still giving you the problem, rather relies on debugger, relies on your own code instead. 4) If all fails, `imgBtnPhoto` is certainly gets refresh somewhere maybe during a transition between the activity and fragment.

Comment: Eurika!. I think I know the problem is. It is `setImageBitmap()`. To use it, you must use `android:src` in the xmls e.g. `android:src="@drawable/android"` and use `setBackground()` if you're using `android:background`  e.g. `android:background="@drawable/android"`. `android:src` for foreground images and `android:background` for background images. So use `setBackground()` if you want to modify `android:backround`.

Comment: @Darkman, I've tried you previous ideas, updated question, however for me, nothing works! I am getting desperate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with `Fragment`s transitions, I've rewritten transition code using [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).